# list index out of range error while using if statement in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python; I've been coding in javascript so I'm not used to all the errors I'm getting.

I'm trying to add properties to an empty object with a for loop, but I get an error saying list index out of range. The error seems to be happening when I add an if statement inside my for loop. I'm not using an index to loop through the seats_info array though. Please help me understand why this is happening, thank you!

```
    seats_info = ['\n1,133,0,A', '\n1,133,2,C', '\n1,133,1,B', '\n1,133,4,E', '\n1,133,3,D', '\n2,132,0,24', '\n2,132,1,25', '\n2,132,2,26']

    def read_manifest(self, manifest):
    file = manifest_dir + '/' + manifest
    data = open(file, 'r')
    seats_info = data.read().split('\r')[1:]
    data.close()

    self.seat_information = {}
    for seat_info in seats_info:
        one_seat = seat_info.split(',')
        section_id = one_seat[0][1:]
        one_seat.remove(one_seat[0])
        one_seat.insert(0, section_id)

        if one_seat[1] not in self.seat_information:
            self.seat_information[one_seat[1]] = [one_seat]
        else:
            self.seat_information[one_seat[1]].append(one_seat)


      Error Message that I received 

      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "path/normalizer.py", line 75, in <module>
normalizer.read_manifest(citifield)
      File "path/normalizer.py", line 36, in read_manifest
     if one_seat[1] not in self.seat_information:
     IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Would recommend just using print statement debugging here. The file format is possibly off from your expectations in a trivial way. By putting a `print seat_info` or `print one_seat` in your loop you'll have a lot more to go off of.

Comment: Javascript would also throw an error accessing a out of bounds array index, yeah?

Comment: You have hardcoded index values like one_seat = seat_info.split(',')
        section_id = one_seat[0][1:] and there are high chances that seat_info.split(',') may return a array which can go beyond the range. Check you data. Recommend to use try block when you are not sure and handle the exception

Comment: -1, we cannot answer this question without either a way to replicate the error with a sample dataset OR without seeing your error. For best measure, could you include the error print out when you run your code?

Comment: I presume the issue is that in the `if` statement, `one_seat` is of length 1. In other words, `one_seat[0]` is in the index but `one_seat[1]` is not, hence the error

Comment: @GeneBurinsky thanks for the tip. I can def add a small sample of the data I have. I checked and one_seat always has a length of at least two.

Thanks everyone for the help. I still don't know what is wrong, since my print logs is giving me what I'm expecting. 
I cloned the repo again, used the same code and I don't get the error message anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a blank line in the data file to reproduce the error.

```
section_id = one_seat[0][1:]
one_seat[0] = section_id
```

At this point, one_seat = [''], so there is no one_seat[1]

```
if one_seat[1] ...
```

Thus list index out of range is correctly raised.

Instead, when you use hard-coded indexes, you may want to verify that your assumptions hold. Here is a sample re-write:

```
def execute():
    seats_info = ['\n', '\n1,133,0,A', '\n1,133,2,C', '\n1,133,1,B', '\n1,133,4,E', '\n1,133,3,D', '\n2,132,0,24', '\n2,132,1,25', '\n2,132,2,26']
    for seat_info in seats_info:
        one_seat = seat_info.split(',')
        if len(one_seat):
            section_id = one_seat[0][1:]
            one_seat[0] = section_id
            # maybe check for a legal section_id here?
            if len(one_seat) > 1:
                row_id = one_seat[1]                
                if row_id not in seat_information:
                    seat_information[row_id] = [one_seat]
                else:
                    seat_information[row_id].append(one_seat)


seat_information = {}
execute()
for row, seats in seat_information.items():
    print "row", row
    for seat in seats:
        print "seat:", seat
```

Answer (score -1):

Although the solution by Kenny Ostrom is well, I would actually suggest pre-processing the data file after reading it in. This way, you don't have to constantly check assumptions and it simplifies the code. Specifically, I had the following in mind:

```
seats_info = ['\n', '\n1,133,0,A', '\n1,133,2,C', '\n1,133,1,B', '\n1,133,4,E', '\n1,133,3,D', '\n2,132,0,24', '\n2,132,1,25', '\n2,132,2,26']

#remove new line and other markup characters
seats_info = [str.strip(s) for s in seats_info]

#remove elements that have no content:     
seats_info = [s for s in seats_info if len(s)>0]
```

so now, `seats_info` is cleaner and won't throw errors at you:

```
In [21]: seats_info
Out[21]:
['1,133,0,A',
 '1,133,2,C',
 '1,133,1,B',
 '1,133,4,E',
 '1,133,3,D',
 '2,132,0,24',
 '2,132,1,25',
 '2,132,2,26']
```

Since currently you're indexing out the `\n` but now you don't have to, you'll have to simplify your data extraction loop to:

```
for seat_info in seats_info:
    one_seat = seat_info.split(',')
    section_id = one_seat[0]

    if one_seat[1] not in seat_information:
        self.seat_information[one_seat[1]] = [one_seat]
    else:
        self.seat_information[one_seat[1]].append(one_seat)
```

Finally, I HIGHLY encourage you to use the `with` statement to read in your data as that is easier on the eyes and, I'd say, more Pythonic. Specifically, consider the following definition for your `read_manifest` function:

```
def read_manifest(self, manifest):
    file = manifest_dir + '/' + manifest

    #read in the file:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        #because we later use str.strip, you don't need to do [1:] to get rid of \r
        seats_info = f.read().split('\r')

    #pre-process:
    seats_info = [str.strip(s) for s in seats_info]     
    seats_info = [s for s in seats_info if len(s)>0]
```